# Which branch is checked out on pull request event in GitHub workflow?

Tags: github-actions

Which branch is checked out on `pull_request` event in GitHub workflow? **Is it the source branch or destination branch?**

For example: Let's say I have a branch `feature` which has been created from `master`, and I create a Pull Request from `feature` to `master` (`master <- feature`), and suppose I have the following code in the workflow files for both the branches, I want to understand which workflow file would run?

**Code on `master` branch**

```
on:
    branches: [ master ]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    
    steps:
    - run: echo "MASTER"
```

**Code on `feature` branch**

```
on:
    branches: [ master ]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - run: echo "FEATURE"
```

In my testing I think the feature branch (source) is checked out, but then why do the array pull_request needs master and not feature (i.e. the destination not the source)?

Comment: Both workflows in your question are invalid. The event is missing in both. Is the question about **which workflow would run** or **which branch would be checked out**? There is no checkout step in your workflows. Please update your question with these details along with how you checkout your code i.e. manually or using `actions/checkout`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The workflow file would be checkout out from your `HEAD`, in this case the `feature` branch.

You can check from where you ran your workflow from your Actions tab:

[image: Github actions branch names]

Also, you can see which version of your workflow file ran it, after you click on the workflow you'll have this tab:

[image: workflow file tab]

And here you'll see the workflow file content at that commit

[image]

But in order to create the workflow in the first time, you have to push it to your repository's default branch, as the documentation mentions:

> Some events also require the workflow file to be present on the default branch of the repository in order to run.

See more:

- https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/triggering-a-workflow#about-workflow-triggers

---

For your second question:

> Why do the array pull_request needs master and not feature?

That array represents that you want to run the workflow if you opened a PR targeting `master`.

You can choose to run a workflow if you open a PR against a branch (e.g `master`), or on push to any branch if you need more flexiblity in managing you pipelines

```
on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - master
  push:
    branches:
      - develop
      - feature/*
```

See:

- https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#pull_request
- https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#running-your-pull_request-workflow-based-on-the-head-or-base-branch-of-a-pull-request

Comment: Also, this workflow run doesn't have access to caches created in `feature` branch (source) but has access to caches created in `master` branch (destination), is that correct?

Comment: Please refer to this [secrtion](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/caching-dependencies-to-speed-up-workflows#restrictions-for-accessing-a-cache) "Workflow runs can restore caches created in either the current branch or the default branch (usually `main`). If a workflow run is triggered for a pull request, it can also restore caches created in the base branch, including base branches of forked repositories."